# Paperclip getting only "/images/original/missing.png"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

I can't get uploaded images appear to the user. Here are things I've tried:

1. rails generate scaffold User name:string age:integer
2. rails generate paperclip User avatar

Related gems in `Gemfile`:

```
gem "paperclip", "= 3.0.4"
gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2"
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

View form (New & Edit):

```
<%= form_for(@user , :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

View (Show):

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Age:</strong>
  <%= @user.age %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Avatar:</strong>
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

Still keep getting only:  `/images/original/missing.png`

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look to paperclip api documentation. You'll see there that you should define the url format for your uploaded images, as well as (not compulsorily though) the path where it will save.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a UsersController or are you using Devise? If so, check your code against mine below.

```
 private

  # Use strong_parameters for attribute whitelisting
  # Be sure to update your create() and update() controller methods.

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end
```